# ffserver crashes with my config file

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, ffserver

I'm running ffserver (avserver version 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) with my own conf file but for some reason ffserver seems to be crashing on startup, no matter what I change in the conf file. When I start ffserver without specifying a custom conf file it seems to be starting OK.

My purpose is to proxy a live audio stream to make it available to an internal network so that the stream is only downloaded over the Internet once.

This is my conf file:

```
Port 8090
BindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 1000
CustomLog -
NoDaemon

<Feed feed1.ffm>
   ACL allow 127.0.0.1
</Feed>

<Stream feed1.mpg>
   Feed feed1.ffm

   Format mp2
   AudioCodec mp3
   AudioBitRate 128
   AudioChannels 2
   AudioSampleRate 44100

   NoVideo
</Stream>
```

This is the error I receive when I start ffserver: `ffserver -f ffserver.conf`:

```
avserver version 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 16 2015 13:17:43 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
*** Error in `ffserver': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x000000000097951e ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

On my system, `ffserver` is a symlink to `avserver`. I have tried `avserver` instead of `ffserver` which has the same results.

**Update:**

It also crashes when I run it with the default conf file as a specific configuration:

```
avserver -f /etc/avserver.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `avserver` crashes when the config file is in any place other than `/etc/avserver.conf`.